# Flutter control slider with keyboard arrows

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make an android tv app with a basic video player using the video_player plugin.
One of the issue I am having is that the slider control for the seek time is not being focused and I cannot drag it with the keyboard.
Is there any way to accomplish this? Maybe with a keyboardlistener?

Thanks